# Need to get aggregation filters result for notequals, equals, contains, not contains, starts with and ends with

Tags: java, mongodb, filtering, aggregation

I have a method which returns filtered result.

```
 private Bson filter() {       
       return Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("product","abc"));
    }
```

The above code returns results where product is equal to abc.
Similarly I need to do get results for not equals, contains, not contains, starts with, ends with.
Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of public methods you could use for this, have a look at the Javadoc here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).